# Windows10マシンを変えたら、Apache2.4で、NAS HDDをエイリアス登録できません。

Tags: apache

Apache2.4ですが、新しいWindowsマシンに移行したら、nttpd.confをコピーしたのに、NAS HDDのエイリアス登録がうまくいきません。
4種類ためしましたが、全部だめです。

```
# NAS HDDのIPアドレスバージョン（￥）
# Alias /video3 "\\192.168.1.2\share">

# <Directory "\\192.168.1.2\share">
# Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
# AllowOverride All
# Require all granted
# </Directory>
```

```
# NAS HDDのデバイス名バージョン
# Alias /video3 "\\LS210DA0C\share"
#
# <Directory "\\LS210DA0C\share">
# Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
# AllowOverride None
# Require all granted
# </Directory>
```

```
# NAS HDDのネットワークドライブ割り当て名
# Alias /video3 "L:/share"
#
# <Directory "L:/share">
# Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
# AllowOverride None
# Require all granted
# </Directory>
```

```
# NAS HDDのIPアドレスバージョン（￥）
# Alias /videov3 "//192.168.1.2/share">
#
# <Directory "//192.168.1.2/share">
# Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
# AllowOverride All
# Require all granted
# </Directory>
```

Comment: 全て`#`でコメントアウトされていて、何も設定していないように見えますが、本当でしょうか？ それから`nttpd.conf`は`httpd.conf`のtypoでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

Apacheを起動しているユーザとネットワークドライブを設定しているユーザは同じですか？
以下の順で確認しみてはいかがでしょうか

1. 起動スクリプトを修正する。
   　1. %USERNAME%入れる
   　2. Netuseコマンドを起動前に仕込む
2. 起動させて状態を確認する

そのほか、すでに確認されていると思いますが、起動時のエラーログなど定時されれば
わりとそのもんずばりの回答に近づけるかと思います。

そのほか、どうやってインストールして、どのフォルダのhttpd.confを修正しているかなども
参考になるかもしれません。